# react native - assigning array of object of state to a variable & updating value of specific element in array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been having a problem in accessing & assigning a state of array in React Native. My code is as follows:

```js
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      boxChecked: [false, false],

      sportCat: []
    }
  }

  arrayHandler = (sportID, value) => {
    this.setState({boxChecked[sportID]: !this.state.boxChecked[sportID]})  //3rd problem
    if (value === true){
      this.setState({sportCat: [...this.state.sportCat, sportID]})
    } else if (value === false) {
      var idx = this.state.sportCat.indexOf(sportID)
      this.state.sportCat.splice(idx, 1)
    } else {
      console.log('boxstat undefined')
    }
    console.log(this.state.sportCat)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <CheckBox
          sportID = { 1 }
          value = { this.state.boxChecked[sportID] }
          onChange = {(sportID, value) => {
            this.arrayHandler(sportID, value)
            console.log(value, 'value') //1st problem
            console.log(sportID, 'sportID')  //2nd problem
          }} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

What I would like to ask are:

---

1. when I try to get the value of `value`, it returns undefined. Is the problem with how I assigned the `sportID` variable?
2. when I try to get the value of `sportID`, it returns `Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, etc...`
3. When I type the `setState` parameter this way, the first `boxChecked[sportID]` turns white instead of blue in Visual Studio, which means the syntax in considered invalid. Is my way to `setState` the array incorrect?

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What I understood by the above code is that you trying a achieve the functionality of multiple checkboxes. you are storing the selected checkbox info in sportCat state that you can use for further processing. Is that so?

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq correct! i try to collect the choosen sport category based on which checkbox is checked by the user. the array is updated each time the user check/uncheck the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problems.

This is how I managed to achieve multiple checkbox functionality.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View, 
  CheckBox,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      sportID: [0,1,2,3],
      boxChecked: [false, false, false],

      sportCat: []
    }
  }

  arrayHandler = (ID) => {

    let boxChecked = [...this.state.boxChecked]  // use spread operator
    boxChecked[ID] = !boxChecked[ID]             // to mutate the value
    this.setState({boxChecked}, () => {          // of specific array
      const value = this.state.boxChecked[ID]
      if (value === true){
        this.setState({sportCat: [...this.state.sportCat, ID]})
      } else if (value === false) {
        var idx = this.state.sportCat.indexOf(ID)
        if (idx > -1){
          this.state.sportCat.splice(idx, 1)
        }
      }
      console.log(this.state.boxChecked)
      console.log(this.state.sportCat)
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CheckBox
          value = { this.state.boxChecked[0] }
          onValueChange = {() => {
            this.arrayHandler(0)
          }} />

        <CheckBox
          value = { this.state.boxChecked[1] }
          onValueChange = {() => {
            this.arrayHandler(1)
        }} />

        <CheckBox
          value = { this.state.boxChecked[2] }
          onValueChange = {() => {
            this.arrayHandler(2)
        }} />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style = {{ borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 5, height: 50, width: 100}} 
          onPress = {() => {
            console.log(this.state.sportCat)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.sportCat))
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

> Turns out that setState() doesn't mutate the value of the state immediately, instead it creates a pending state transition. Accessing the value of state immediately after calling setState() method might return the unchanged value of the state. You must invoke a second callback function to setState(), as setState occurs asynchronously.

Moreover, mutating the value of specific index of array directly in the onValueChange component is not possible, you have to use the spread operator function.

Answer (score 0):

onChange return the native element , 
use onValueChange it call the function with a boolean if it is checked or not
This is an example of the Checkbox Implementation

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'column'}}>
  <CheckBox />
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <CheckBox
      value={this.state.checked}
      onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
    />
    <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}> this is checkbox</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

For setState issue, you need to update the whole array not direct assignments.

You also seem to be modifying the State without using setState here,

this.state.sportCat.splice(idx, 1)

Which is not a good thing to do.
I think you need to go through the docs more

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can manipulate the state directly from the component event

Try these:

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      boxChecked: [false, false],

      sportCat: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <CheckBox
          value = { this.state.boxChecked[0] }
          onValueChange = {() => { this.setState({ boxChecked[0]: !this.state.boxChecked[0] }) }} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve your problem. You can define a Array of Object and each Object will contain the properties of a checkbox. This way you can dynamically define the checkboxes.

```
  checkboxes =  [
    { id: 1, isChecked:false, sportID: 20}, 
    { id: 2, isChecked:false, sportID: 25}, 
    { id: 3, isChecked:false, sportID: 30}
  ]
```

Below code shows the use of the above Object.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   checkboxes:  [           
     { id: 1, isChecked:false, sportID: 20}, 
     { id: 2, isChecked:false, sportID: 25}, 
     { id: 3, isChecked:false, sportID: 30}
  ]
}
// Function To get The list of selected sports
getListOfSelectedSports(){
  selectedSports = [];
  this.state.checkBoxes.map((checkbox)=> { if(checkbox.isChecked)  selectedSports.push(checkbox.sportID) })
  return selectedSports;
}

renderCheckboxes(){
  return this.state.checkBoxes.map((checkbox, index, checkBoxArray) =>
      <CheckBox
        key={checkbox.id}
        style={{alignSelf:'center', margin:15}}
        onValueChange={(toggleValue) => {
            checkBoxArray[index].isChecked = toggleValue;
            this.setState({checkBoxes:checkBoxArray});
        }}
        value={ checkbox.isChecked }
      />
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.renderCheckboxes()}
          .....
     //Rest of you Code
  )
}
```